# Conditional `try` statement with a "general" exception message

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.6, try-except

I want to `try` to load a file if a conditional is true. I want a second (one line) bit of code to execute if either a file exception occurs or the conditional is false.

In order to involve birds, consider the following code:

```
if try_to_fly:
    try:
        fly()
    except FlyError:
        walk("I'm walking instead of flying.")
else:
    walk("I'm walking stead of flying.")

# more lines below #
```

This does what I want to do. But, it has the line `walk("I'm walking stead of flying.")` twice, which would be nice to avoid.

Also, there's more code to do below this bit, so we can't `return` in the try statement without accounting for that code.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All answers is good, but this might help you:

```
try:
    if try_to_fly:
        fly()
    else:
        raise FlyError()
except FlyError:
    walk("I'm walking instead of flying.")
```

Comment: @TaohidulIslam it is not similar, I guessed that he doesn't want to use `walk("I'm walking instead of flying.")` twice.

Comment: All the answers helpful and I appreciate it. I chose this because it seemed shortest and easiest to read; raising a `FlyError` right before an `except FlyError:` line seems easy for a reader to understand. Thanks again all.

Comment: @TaohidulIslam, you might have made a typo. You have `walk("I'm walking instead of flying.")` twice. :p

Comment: @JayCalamari that is exactly what I am saying to him, but he just down voted my answer :DD

Comment: oh, it was my fault. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

Without using any additional variable:

```
try:
    if try_to_fly:
        fly()
    else:
        walk("I'm walking stead of flying.")
except FlyError:
    walk("I'm walking instead of flying.")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set a variable if flying was successful.

```
flying = False
if try_to_fly:
    try:
        fly()
        flying = True
    except FlyError:
        pass
if not flying:
    walk("I'm walking instead of flying.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Guess you want this: the *try / except / else* this way saves you from other *if statements*

```
class FlyError(Exception): pass

def fly(tickets=True):

    if tickets:
       # ...
       verify = True
       # etc
    else:
       raise FlyError("no tickets")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    for tickets in [ None, True]:
        try:
            print("My tickets: ", tickets)
            fly(tickets)
        except FlyError as e:
            print("I'm walking instead of flying.")
        else:
            print("Nicely by plane!")
```

Output:

```
('My tickets: ', None)
I'm walking instead of flying.
('My tickets: ', True)
Nicely by plane!
```

Comment: This answer is really cool and well thought out, and I might use something like this in the future. But since it needs `fly` to look at `tickets` and raise the `FlyError`, it means changing `fly`, which isn't ideal in my case right now. I appreciate it anyway. (And I like that `FlyError` became a real exception :). )

Comment: you are calling fly() in the try/except, so I introduced a fly() that raise an exception to simulate. You can make that whatever you want. So, if your fly() raise an exception on other condition that is fine

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, but then what about `try_to_fly`? `fly` can fail or not on its own, but on top of that, if `try_to_fly` is false the code should act like it failed regardless. (Either way, I might use a setup like yours in the future, so thanks :). )

Comment: you have serveral solutions to go on, think about what you want exactly, that might have changed on these inputs. Maybe some new insights let you merge some of it

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `bool` flag

```
b_need_print = True

if try_to_fly:
    try:
        fly()
        b_need_print = False
    except FlyError:
        pass

if b_need_print:
    walk("I'm walking stead of flying.")
```

Comment: Almost same of khelwood's answer :(

Comment: I have think of it, before i see it, and I write it in my pycharm.(his answer is fast).

Comment: My variable is more readable.And I have test my code in mycharm.

Comment: oh! okay :) nice one